# pseudo class vertical-align

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

when I delete the vertical-align in div.content:before selector, the text will pull down and can't show completely, so what's the pseudo class do and why this works? 
PS: Is there any other way to implement like the demo shows, namely align the text in the middle and text will begin in a new line if it is too long.

here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yougen/8WhNZ/

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <span>Mix Color Lace Dress</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

css:

> div.wrapper {
>           position: relative;
>           width:120px;
>       }
>
> ```
> div.content {
>     width: 120px;
>     height: 80px;
>     text-align: center;
>     background: rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
> }
>
> div.content:before {
>     content: '';
>     display: inline-block;
>     height: 100%;
>     vertical-align: middle;
>     margin-right: -0.25em;
> }
>
> div.content span {
>     display: inline-block;
>     width: 80px;
>     font-size: 14px;
>     font-weight: bold;
>     vertical-align: middle;
>     color: white;
> }
> ```

Comment: Why you want remove this? It is necessary for this trick to work. The alignmenet of all the emelemnts in a line has to be middle to show it in the middle.

Comment: I want to know how does this trick work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The before pseudo element is just at the left of your real content. Its function is to have a 100% of the height of the container and precisely has a vertical-align: middle to force every element on the same line (in this case, your span) with the same vertical-align: middle to be shown in the middle of the container, although it hasn't the 100% of the height.

This trick is used when you don't know the height of the element that you want to align in the middle. In other cases you can play with vertical margins, for example, but here we need a pseudoelement with a known height (100% of the container).

Look at that: http://jsfiddle.net/7hUqs/

```
#element-1 {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#element-2 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#element-3 {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: green;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#element-4 {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: pink;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The vertical-align: middle works with the silbing elements that have the same came of vertical-align. All of them, as a block, will be aligned with the other elements of the line and its vertical alignement (in this case, top). And the height of the line is the maximum height of its elements, not the height of the container. A little weird, but this is the thing.

Comment: Chris Coyier wrote a nice article explaining it in its entirety here: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Yes! I was searching for this article. Thank you.

Comment: you mean when set an element vertical-align, other elements in the same line will also be the same behavior in the containing block?

Comment: key points to understand: vertical-align only works on elements with display: inline-block, and they have to be sibling elements in order to affect each other. But we don't want to have to add an actual html element inline just to affect the element we need, so we do it with a pseudo element

Comment: I edit the answer to show the strange behaviour that justifies why we need a 100% height pseudo-element with vertical-align: middle, and why the real element also needs this alignement.

Comment: @davidgnin, for your example, when change #element-2 vertical-align value, the other element will also be affected, so in the same line, the maximum element's vertical-align is the baseline? and the silbling elements vertical-align is relative to it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div.content:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
}
div.content span {
    display: inline;
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8WhNZ/3/)

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to align the text to the top, I just want to know the reason why can't delete the vertical-align in the peusdo class

Comment: by default div cant give vertical-align because div display is block but dispaly:inline-block can give it

Comment: And inline elements can't have a height. That's why the trick doesn't work in this case. To have both behaviours: height and vertical-align, we need the inline-block display. And of course the vertical-align: middle on all the elements of the line.